# Python, UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: csv, encoding, python-3.3

Hello I've got this piece of code

```
import urllib.request
import string
import time
import gzip
from io import BytesIO
from io import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import date
import concurrent.futures

den = date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
url = '' + den.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '_OB_ADR_csv.zip'

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
zipdata = BytesIO()
zipdata.write(data)

csvfile = open('./test.csv', 'w', newline='')
csvwrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')

with ZipFile(zipdata) as zip:
    for i, nazev in enumerate(zip.namelist()):
        if i == 0:
            continue

        csvstring = StringIO(str(zip.read(nazev), encoding='windows-1250'))
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvstring, delimiter=';')

        for j, row in enumerate(csvreader):
            if j == 0 and i != 1:
                continue

            csvwrite.writerow(row)

csvfile.close()
```

When i run it it sometimes throws "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)" at "csvwrite.writerow(row)"

How can I solve this issue? Thank you.

EDIT:
I run it under Python 3.3

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell csv.writer about the encoding. Take a look at the [pydocs for the csv module](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/csv.html):

> To decode a file using a different encoding, use the encoding argument
>   of open...[t]he same applies to writing in something other than the
>   system default encoding: specify the encoding argument when opening
>   the output file.

You can see from the UnicodeEncodeError that Python thinks you want the file written in ascii. Just specify the encoding parameter and choose your desired encoding (my suggestion is `encoding='utf-8'`).

Comment: I forgot to write that I run it under python 3.2